# Split triangle sphere grid to hexagonal (Goldberg hexasphere)

Tags: algorithm

I've create this lil sphere from icosahedron using subdivision method. [image]Now i want split it to hexagonal tiles[image], but i realy don't know how to do this! i've tried to remove every third vertice to create hexagonal gid out of points but in this method i cant triangulate this hexagons[image]. Maybe someone know algorhitm to do this?

Comment: You do realize that you'll be left with 12 pentagons afterwards, right?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but 3 points define a plane, are you garanteed that the 6 points are in the same plane?

Comment: @maraca  yeah, that will work but i have my triangles in int array and vertices in vector array so to this method needs to check all elements of vertice array and that is too slow

Comment: @yurikilochek shure, it's visibe on my screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Goldberg sphere is the dual of a geodesic sphere, which you have already constructed.

You can create it by connecting the "center point" of each triangle to the center points of the 3 adjacent triangles.  Each vertex in the geodesic sphere will then become a face.

In order to ensure that the resulting faces are all planar, the appropriate definition of a triangle "center point" is just the intersection of the faces at each of its corners.  At each corner, construct a plane tangent to the sphere, and then find the intersection of these 3 planes.

Note that the resulting polyhedron will be a tiny bit bigger -- it will enclose the sphere that you're approximating, whereas the geodesic sphere was enclosed by it.  Also the resulting hexagons aren't exactly regular, but quite close.

Comment: this is right! but this method is too slow, maybe any more optimal solutions exists? i mean maybe i can modify subdivide algotithm?